# SDK support repository not in list

Tags: android, android-studio

My SDK options do not display Support Repository. How do I get that SDK to list in the attached?

[image]

Comment: One does not need it, it's perfectly save to uninstall.

Comment: I'm not getting my databinding to work even when Enable = True is added to my gradle file. ActivityMainBinding doesnt work and from the two tutorials I've looked at they require the support repository to be ticked in the SDK.

Comment: When the XML has no `<data />` tag, it won't generate any `ViewDataBinding` class for it. `androidx.databinding` is the group name, but one does not have to add a dependency.